# Using ANTLR 4 to parse TSQL Joins in Views, Stored Procedures and Functions

Tags: sql-server, parsing, token, antlr4

Looking for some validation on the approach to using ANTLR 4 to parse SQL joins.

I have generated a lexer, parser and visitor from the following grammar.

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/tsql

I can then create a parse tree (in this example for a view) and I can kick off a walk of tree using a listener I have implemented.

```
ICharStream stream = CharStreams.fromstring(view);
ITokenSource lexer = new TSqlLexer(stream);
ITokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
TSqlParser parser = new TSqlParser(tokens);
parser.BuildParseTree = true;
IParseTree tree = parser.create_view();

TSqlListener listener = new TSqlListener();
ParseTreeWalker.Default.Walk(listener, tree);
```

My question is. Is my method of extracting the tokens for the joins the 'correct' and most efficient way of doing this.

My implementation is below and i based on listening for a walk of the tree at the join conditions. I need to capture table aliases and relate them to columns so I need to be in the same context when I'm walking the tree. Hence I'm manually descending in a single method.

```
public void EnterTable_sources([NotNull] TSqlParser.Table_sourcesContext context)
{
    var table_sources = context.table_source().ToList();

    foreach (var table_source in table_sources)
    {
        var item = table_source.table_source_item_joined();

        if (item != null)
        {
            //first aliases
            var source_item = item.table_source_item();

            if (source_item != null)
            {
                TableAlias tableAlias = new TableAlias();

                var table_name = source_item.table_name_with_hint();

                if (table_name != null)
                {
                    var fullTableName = table_name.GetText();

                    if (fullTableName.Contains('.'))
                    {
                        var nameParts = fullTableName.Split('.').ToList();

                        for (int i = 0; i <nameParts.Count; i++)
                        {
                            tableAlias.AddParts(nameParts);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tableAlias.AddParts(fullTableName);
                    }
                }

                var table_alias = source_item.as_table_alias();

                if (table_alias != null)
                {
                    tableAlias.Alias = table_alias.GetText();
                }

                JoinAnalysis.Aliases.Add(tableAlias);
            }

            var join_parts = item.join_part();

            foreach (var join_part in join_parts)
            {
                var table_source_joins = join_part.table_source();

                if (table_source_joins != null)
                {
                    //The join table and alias
                    var table_source_item_joined = table_source_joins.table_source_item_joined();

                    if (table_source_item_joined != null)
                    {
                        var joinAlias = new TableAlias();
                        var table_source_item = table_source_item_joined.table_source_item();
                        var table_name = table_source_item.table_name_with_hint();

                        if (table_name != null)
                        {
                            var fullTableName = table_name.GetText();

                            if (fullTableName.Contains('.'))
                            {
                                var nameParts = fullTableName.Split('.').ToList();
                                joinAlias.AddParts(nameParts);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                joinAlias.AddParts(fullTableName);
                            }
                        }

                        if (table_source_item != null)
                        {
                            var table_alias = table_source_item.as_table_alias();

                            if (table_alias != null)
                            {
                                joinAlias.Alias = table_alias.GetText();
                            }
                        }

                        if (joinAlias.Alias != null)
                        {
                            JoinAnalysis.Aliases.Add(joinAlias);
                        }
                    }
                }

                var search_condition = join_part.search_condition();

                if (search_condition != null)
                {
                    //The join conditions
                    var conditions = search_condition.search_condition_and();

                    if (conditions != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var condition in conditions)
                        {
                            if (condition != null)
                            {
                                foreach (var search_condition_not in condition.search_condition_not())
                                {
                                    JoinCondition joinCondition = new JoinCondition();
                                    joinCondition.LineNumber = search_condition_not.Start.Line;
                                    var conditionText = search_condition_not.GetText();
                                    joinCondition.JoinConditionText = conditionText;
                                    var splitCondition = conditionText.Split("=");

                                    if (splitCondition.Length == 2)
                                    {
                                        joinCondition.LeftPart = splitCondition[0];
                                        joinCondition.RightPart = splitCondition[1];
                                    }

                                    JoinAnalysis.JoinConditions.Add(joinCondition);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this using all of the other listener methods that have been generated without manually descending into child nodes? I there some magic that I'm missing that holds context between nodes as they are walked?

Comment: Not to undercut the validity of this question, but for .NET there already is a [T-SQL parser](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser) written by Microsoft themselves. It has a relatively simple visitor interface; [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27305052/4137916) of it being used to parse joins (for the slightly different goal of finding references to other databases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually drilling down to sub elements in a rule you can simply listen to the the enter/exit calls for these subrules. As an example: you listen to `table_sources` and descent to `table_source_item_joined` from there to `table_name_with_hint`. Instead you could simply override the `EnterTable_name_with_hint` method.

It is totally ok to write a listener, which only handles very specific parts of the language. Look at [this (C++) code in MySQL Workbench](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/modules/db.mysql.parser/src/ObjectListeners.h), where I created several listeners, each just handling a subpart of a larger construct or individual objects. There are listeners for create table, alter table, column definitions, triggers and more.